# Rendering Associate Data (has_many, :through) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations, render

I have two navigation bars (placement & ad) that define the content of the page (adtype). The first navigation bar, placement, is always visible at the top. The second navigation bar, ad, will render on the left side of the page based on what attribute is chosen at the top in the placement. Model placement & model ad have many to many relationship. How can I render the second navigation, ad, in html based on what attribute is chosen in the top navigation bar, placement?

Two navigation models are:

```
class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :placementname  
  has_many :adtypes, :foreign_key => "placement_id"  
  has_many :ads, :through => :adtypes   
end


class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :adname  
  has_many :adtypes, :foreign_key => "ad_id"  
  has_many :placements, :through => :adtypes  
end
```

Here is the model for the content, adtype, that depends on what attributes are chosen in the navigation bars:

```
class Adtype < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :adtype_screenshot, :location, :placement_screemshot, :specs  
  belongs_to :placements  
  belongs_to :ads  
end
```

Here is my schema database:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121127052112) do  
  create_table "ads", :force => true do |t|  
    t.string   "adname"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end 

  create_table "adtypes", :force => true do |t|  
    t.integer  "placement_id"  
    t.integer  "ad_id"  
    t.string   "location"  
    t.string   "placement_screenshot"  
    t.string   "adtype_screenshot"  
    t.string   "specs"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end

  create_table "placements", :force => true do |t|  
    t.string   "placementname"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end    
end
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :placements do  
    resources :ads do  
      resources :adtypes do  
      end  
    end  
  end
```

Here is how I am rendering my top navigation (_navigation.html.erb) and linking each attribution to a new url that ends with the placement id (http://localhost:3000/placements/2)

```
<% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>  
  <li ><%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id) %> </li>  
<%end%>
```

Comment: Which controller action or actions need to render the _ad_ navigation bar? Is it just `placements#show` or is it supposed to be a standard template across the entire site?

Comment: It is supposed to be across the entire site. Though I just found the solution. First, I had these as plural by mistake:
  belongs_to :placements  
  belongs_to :ads  
So I just got rid of the 's' and rendered my ads this way (ads view show) :
      <% @placement.ads.all.each do |ad| %>
        <li> <%= link_to ad.adname, placement_ad_path(@placement, ad) %> </li>
    <%end%>
   
Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Sorry, I should have caught that. You might want to create an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: First, I had these as plural by mistake:

```
belongs_to :placements 
belongs_to :ads
```

So I just got rid of the 's' and rendered my ads this way (ads view show):

```
<% @placement.ads.all.each do |ad| %>  
<%= link_to ad.adname, placement_ad_path(@placement, ad) %>  
<%end%>
```